# Send json from file in requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to send a json file to a url (post). I am using data parameter to open the file and send it to the url:

```
r = requests.post(url_info, data=open(f, 'rb'), headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This works right now but I have been asked to use "json" insteand of "data" to send the file.

I have seen some examples using json created as dictionaries where this is working but I am not able to make it work from a file.

I have tried to use it directly:

```
json=open(f, 'rb')
```

In f I have the route to the json file.
Serialize the json file with json.dumps(open.... But I always get a message telling me that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `json` module to load JSON data from the file.

```py
import requests
import json

# open the file and load JSON data from it
with open(f, "r") as file:
    data = json.load(f)  # type(data) -> <class 'dict'>
# send POST request with the loaded data
r = requests.post(url_info, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony.C I just changed data=data to json=data and it worked!